# R heatmap with circles

Tags: r, heatmap

I would like to generate, in R, a heatmap visualization of a matrix using circles, in order to have both the color and diameter of the circles be informative. Something looking like this:
[image: example R heatmap with circles]

This sort of plotting is called "bubblegum plot" in certain computational biology labs, but I could not find an R function/package to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure whether there is a package which offers this out-of-the-box but using just `ggplot2` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

d <- data.frame(
  x = rep(paste("Team", LETTERS[1:8]), 4),
  y = rep(paste("Task", 1:4), each = 8),
  value = runif(32)
)

ggplot(d, aes(x, forcats::fct_rev(y), fill = value, size = value)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, stroke = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(.5, 4.5, 1), size = .2) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_radius(range = c(1, 15)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "orange", high = "blue", breaks = c(0, .5, 1), labels = c("Great", "OK", "Bad"), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 8)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA, color = "black", stroke = .25), 
                             label.position = "bottom",
                             title.position = "right", 
                             order = 1),
         fill = guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = NA, title.position = "top", order = 2)) +
  labs(size = "Area = Time Spent", fill = "Score:", x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Only thing missing: the package "forcats" needs to be installed. Also, your solution works great even if there are two different variables assocaited to diameter and fill. I also appreciate your choice for seed number

Comment: (: Yep. Sometimes I'm a bit lazy and forget about specifying all the packages explicitly. But if you have the tidy verse installed then you already have forcats. But you could do without forcats by using `factor(y, levels = rev(levels(factor(y))))`.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an alternative function to perform the plotting, without ggplot and tidyverse. I will soon upload it to the [CRAN corto package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corto/index.html). Enjoy!

[image: Bubblegum plot]

#### Usage

```
inputp<-matrix(runif(1000),nrow=50)
inputn<-matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=50)
colnames(inputp)<-colnames(inputn)<-paste0("Score",1:ncol(inputp))
rownames(inputp)<-rownames(inputn)<-paste0("Car",1:nrow(inputp))
par(las=2,mar=c(0,6,6,10))
bubblegum(inputp,inputn)
```

#### BUBBLEGUM function

```
require(gplots)
require(plotrix)
bubblegum<-function(
    inputp,
    inputn,
    pcr=0.1,
    grid=FALSE,
    reorder=FALSE,
    legend=TRUE,
    matrix2col=TRUE
) {
    if(nrow(inputp)!=nrow(inputn)|ncol(inputp)!=ncol(inputn)){
        warning("inputp and inpute have different sizes!")
    }
    
    ### Initialize
    rownumber<-nrow(inputp)
    colnumber<-ncol(inputp)
    
    ### Trasform the NESs into colors
    if(matrix2col){
        colconversion<-matrix2col(inputn,nbreaks=20)
        nescolors<-colconversion$colormatrix
    } else {
        nescolors<-inputn
    }

    #pradii<-0.3*(-log(inputp)/max(-log(inputp)))
    pradii<-inputp
    pradii[inputp>0.1]<-pcr*0
    pradii[inputp<=0.1]<-pcr*1
    pradii[inputp<0.05]<-pcr*2
    pradii[inputp<1E-5]<-pcr*3
    pradii[inputp<1E-10]<-pcr*4
    pradii[inputp<1E-20]<-pcr*5
    
    ### Order by sum NES
    sumnes<-apply(inputn,1,function(x){sum(abs(x))})
    if(reorder){
        neworder<-order(sumnes)
        pradii<-pradii[neworder,]
        nescolors<-nescolors[neworder,]
    } else {
        pradii<-pradii[nrow(pradii):1,]
        nescolors<-nescolors[nrow(nescolors):1,]
    }
    
    ### Plot
    #par(las=2,mar=c(0,20,6,0))
    plot(0,ylim=c(0,rownumber+1),xlim=c(0,colnumber+1),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",type="n",frame.plot=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")#,xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
    if(grid){
        abline(h=1:rownumber,lty=2)
        abline(v=1:colnumber,lty=2)
    }
    for (i in (1:rownumber)) {
        for(j in 1:colnumber) {
            radius<-pradii[i,j]
            color<-nescolors[i,j]
            draw.circle(j,i,radius=radius,col=color,lwd=0.2)
        }
    }
    axis(3,at=1:colnumber,labels=colnames(pradii))
    axis(2,at=1:rownumber,labels=rownames(pradii),cex.axis=0.7)
    
    ### Enable things to be drawn outside the plot region
    par(xpd=TRUE)
    
    ### Title
    
    
    ### Legend
    if(legend){
        #legend(-colnumber,rownumber,c("group A", "group B"), pch = c(1,2), lty = c(1,2))
        legend("topright",inset=c(-0.1,0),legend=c(
            "<0.1","0.05","<1e-5","<1e-10","<1e-20"
        ), pch=c(21), title="FDR",pt.bg="white",horiz=FALSE,pt.cex=c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3))
    }
    
    if(matrix2col){
        extreme<-round(max(abs(inputn)),1)
        legend("bottomright", inset=c(-0.1,0),legend=c(
            -extreme,-extreme/2,0,extreme/2,extreme
        ), pch=c(21), title="Score",
        pt.bg=colconversion$col[c(1,5,10,15,19)],
        horiz=FALSE,pt.cex=3)
    }
    
    
}

###########################
matrix2col<-function(z,col1="navy",col2="white",col3="red3",nbreaks=100,center=TRUE){
    if(center){
        extreme=max(abs(z))+0.001
        breaks <- seq(-extreme, extreme, length = nbreaks)
    }else {
        breaks <- seq(min(z), max(z), length = nbreaks)
    }
    ncol <- length(breaks) - 1
    col <- colorpanel(ncol,col1,col2,col3)
    CUT <- cut(z, breaks=breaks)
    colorlevels <- col[match(CUT, levels(CUT))] # assign colors to heights for each point
    names(colorlevels)<-rownames(z)
    
    colormatrix<-matrix(colorlevels,ncol=ncol(z),nrow=nrow(z))
    dimnames(colormatrix)<-dimnames(z)
    return(list(colormatrix=colormatrix,col=col))
}
```